# python kivy app stops functioning after adding widget (on PC)

Tags: python, kivy

I removed everything superfluous, leaving only what was necessary to reproduce the same behavior.
There is an MD Text Field in which, when entering text, if there are matches, MDDropdownMenu appears with options to choose from. The options are stored in the P_LIST list. If you don't enter text into this Mytextfield, everything works. As soon as you enter the text, the function is triggered, a menu appears, you select. After that, the application does not function.

I determined that this is happening because of the line: self.add_widget(list drop down) # <----------- marked in the code

The menu appears without add_widget, but if you enter more than one letter, a new instance of the ListDropdownValue class is created each time and the menus overlap.

```
#kivymd 0.104.2
#kivy 2.0.0

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

kv_str = """
<StartScreen>:
    startscreen_textfield_1: textfield_id
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                MDTextField:
                    id: textfield_id
                    on_text:
                        root.open_listdropdown(textfield_id)#
            BoxLayout:
                MDTextField:
            BoxLayout:
                MDTextField:
"""
P_LIST = ["ASD", "SDF", "AASD"]

def search_product(prefix):
    filtered_list = []
    filtered_list = list(filter(lambda l: l.startswith(prefix), P_LIST))
    return filtered_list


class MyListDropdownValue(MDDropdownMenu):

    def __init__(self, dropdown_list, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown_list_id = dropdown_list

    def list_dropdown(self):
        if len(self.dropdown_list_id.text) != 0:
            prefix = self.dropdown_list_id.text.upper()
            filtered_list = search_product(prefix)
            menu_items = [{'text':f'{value}',
                       "height": dp(56),
                       "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                       "on_release": lambda x= f"{value}": self.set_item(x)}
                          for value in filtered_list]
            self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
                caller=self.dropdown_list_id,
                items=menu_items,
                width_mult=5,
                )
            self.menu.open()

    def set_item(self, value):
        def set_item(interval):
            self.dropdown_list_id.text = value
            self.menu.dismiss()
        Clock.schedule_once(set_item, 0.1)


class StartScreen(BoxLayout):
    startscreen_textfield_1 = ObjectProperty()

    def open_listdropdown(self, id):
        if len(self.children) == 1:
            listdropdown = MyListDropdownProduct(id)
            self.add_widget(listdropdown)
            self.children[0].list_dropdown()
        else:
            self.children[0].menu.dismiss()
            self.children[0].list_dropdown()



kv = Builder.load_string(kv_str)

class Program(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = StartScreen()
        return self.screen


def main():
    app = Program()
    app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MyListDropdownValue(MDDropdownMenu) class inherits from a MDDropdownMenu.

Then you make dropdown instance with

```
openlistdrop_down = MyDropdownValue(id)
```

Then you add that instance every time you "on_text" with

```
self.add_widget(listdropdown)
```

So you are adding multiple dropdowns.

In Kv try changing

```
on_text:
    root.open_listdropdown(textfield_id)
```

To

```
on_validate:
    root.open_listdropdown(textfield_id)
```

Then the user will need to hit enter before the list is made instead of with every letter added.

Comment: OK, I rewrote the `open_lis dropdown' function.
Now it does not create many new instances of the `mylistdropdownvalue' class. But the problem remained. The Kivy documentation warns not to manipulate the list of children. Probably my approach is wrong.